# SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service failing to start in ms sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Since the above service is not starting, I am not at all able to connect to my local database. The server was working fine since many days. But I don't know what happened all of sudden the sql server service is now failing to start.

**I am getting following error message when try to connect to local db:**
[image]

**When try to start MSSQLSERVER manually from configuration manager:**
[image]

**Errors in my windows event logs:**
[image]
[image]

I've tried following solutions but none of them are working in my case:
[link 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/383bc31d-5d87-4e07-b2fb-acbfbe5776a1/sql-server-2008-not-starting?forum=sqldisasterrecovery) [link 2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180965%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) [link 3](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/03/29/sql-server-fix-error-the-request-failed-or-the-service-did-not-respond-in-timely-fashion-consult-the-event-log-or-other-applicable-error-logs-for-details/) [link 4](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/03/29/sql-server-fix-error-the-request-failed-or-the-service-did-not-respond-in-timely-fashion-consult-the-event-log-or-other-applicable-error-logs-for-details/)

Now I am completely blocked what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which network protocols are enabled?

Comment: The error in SQL Server Management Studio is just a reflection of the issue in the service. The error in the service states the provider as "Named Pipes"; in SQL Server Configuration, have you tried disabling "Named Pipes" and enabling "TCP/IP"?

Comment: Thanks tried your solution... Worked absolutely... Disabled Named pipes, VIA and enabled TCP/IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled Named pipes, VIA and enabled TCP/IP and now everything working correctly.